# Text not displaying in ios app (REACT-NATIVE)

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo

The Text appear/ display in ANDROID but in IOS not. Only the images what appear/display.

```
           <Block center>
                <Block middle>
                <Image source={Images.LogoOnboarding} style={styles.logo} />
                  <Text color="black" size={10} style={{ textAlign: "center", width: 200, position: 'relative'}}  >
                  Take control of what your kids watch on the internet.{"\n"}{"\n"}
                  Discover kid-friendly channels for your kids.{"\n"}
                  Choose only the creators that make family- friendly videos.</Text>
                  <Image source={Images.LogoOnboarding2} style={styles.logo2} /> 
                </Block>
              </Block>
```

Here's my code of the style:

```
logo: {
    width: 100,
    height: 100,
    zIndex: 2,
    position: 'relative',
    marginTop: '-50%'
  },
  logo2: {
    width: 400,
    height: 40,
    zIndex: 2,
    position: 'absolute',
    resizeMode: 'contain',
    marginBottom: 50

  }
```

Comment: Try Platform.ios and find any changes occurs

Answer (score 1):

Add height in style of text
**Example**

```
<Text color="black" size={10} style={{ textAlign: "center", width: 200, height: 80, position: 'relative'}}  >Take control of what your kids watch on the internet.{"\n"}{"\n"}
                  Discover kid-friendly channels for your kids.{"\n"}
                  Choose only the creators that make family- friendly videos.
</Text>
```

Answer (score 0):

None of `color` and `size` props belongs to Text component. Consider to use `color` and `fontSize` properties of `style` object instead. I'm not 100% sure that it is the reason of having text invisible on iOS but it might be :)